# Version Increasing with ContinuousDelivery mode in GitVersion

Tags: .net, git, gitversion

I am new in gitversion and I am trying to understand. This following setting is I need to understand.

```
 tag-prefix: '[vV]'
    next-version: 1.0
    ignore:
      sha: []

branches:
  master:
    regex: master
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  release:
    regex: releases?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
  feature:
    regex: GitVersion_Test-[0-9]*-.*$
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: feature
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  pull-request:
    regex: (pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)[-/]'
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  hotfix:
    regex: hotfix(es)?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  support:
    regex: support[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  develop:
    regex: dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: unstable
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
```

I created gitversion.yml and paste this setting. then I add this file into my project where git folder exists. Then I change something at project and commit this to develop branch. Here is original

```
{
  "Major":1,
  "Minor":0,
  "Patch":0,
  "PreReleaseTag":"unstable.6",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash":"-unstable.6",
  "PreReleaseLabel":"unstable",
  "PreReleaseNumber":6,
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber":6,
  "BuildMetaData":"",
  "BuildMetaDataPadded":"",
  "FullBuildMetaData":"Branch.develop.Sha.7876363f4f7e662558e41e845e7407ade052c7ae",
  "MajorMinorPatch":"1.0.0",
  "SemVer":"1.0.0-unstable.6",
  "LegacySemVer":"1.0.0-unstable6",
  "LegacySemVerPadded":"1.0.0-unstable0006",
  "AssemblySemVer":"1.0.0.0",
  "AssemblySemFileVer":"1.0.0.0",
  "FullSemVer":"1.0.0-unstable.6",
  "InformationalVersion":"1.0.0-unstable.6+Branch.develop.Sha.7876363f4f7e662558e41e845e7407ade052c7ae",
  "BranchName":"develop",
  "EscapedBranchName":"develop",
  "Sha":"7876363f4f7e662558e41e845e7407ade052c7ae",
  "ShortSha":7876363,
  "NuGetVersionV2":"1.0.0-unstable0006",
  "NuGetVersion":"1.0.0-unstable0006",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2":"unstable0006",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTag":"unstable0006",
  "VersionSourceSha":"e94534859c2c0d4f3eeb215e34fc4b5990a9ff08",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource":6,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded":"0006",
  "CommitDate":"2020-08-12"
}
```

So minor should be increased right? but why It does not increase? I am very new this.

Update

Every time I commit to develop branch, Its increase `"PreReleaseTag":"unstable.6"` and other eg. `"unstable.7"` then `"unstable.8"`

> **Update**

I minimize my test and change like that=>

Gitversion.yml

```
next-version: 1.0
branches:
  develop:
    regex: develop$    
    increment: Minor
```

If I use default `mode: ContinuousDelivery`, It does not increase the minor.

But If change `mode: mainline`, its increase the minor

GitVersion.yml

```
next-version: 1.0
mode: Mainline
branches:
  develop:
    regex: develop$
    is-mainline: true
    increment: Minor
```

How can I increase version with ContinuousDelivery mode?